# "MobileNavigationHandler" does NOT exist anymore in PrimeFaces 7

Tags: jsf, primefaces

The scenario is a mobile page developed with JSF and Primeface Mobile. I want to navigate in the same xhtml page between multiple pages (have a look at: [JSF Primefaces Mobile navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39876283/jsf-primefaces-mobile-navigation)). After upgrading PrimeFaces from version 6.1 to 7.0 `org.primefaces.mobile.application.MobileNavigationHandler` does NOT exist anymore. What do i need to use instead? The migration guide "6.2 to 7.0" (https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/wiki/Migration-Guide) doesnt help me: "[...] Mobile has been removed in favor of responsive features. [...]"

Answer (score 2):

There is **NO** migration path for you other than rewriting your code.

PrimeFaces Mobile was completely removed in 7.0
See this blog post from Primefaces: https://www.primefaces.org/primefaces-6-2-roadmap/

> PF Mobile is a renderkit for the existing components however we’ve
>   just realized that we have to maintain two different sets at the same
>   time so decided to deprecate PF Mobile and focus on the responsiveness
>   of the standard renderkit. So in 6.2, mobile will be deprecated and
>   removed in 7.0.

Comment: The question acknowledges that Mobile was removed and is asking for a migration path, this is not an answer.

Comment: The answer implies there is NO migration path. I will update my answer.

Comment: Correct, so it becomes either opinion based or ' off-site resources' so not aeal quedtion for stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my migrated fork: https://github.com/djmj/primefaces-mobile.

I extracted the mobile components from PrimeFaces 6.1 and adapted them to PrimeFaces 7.0 as a separate library. I did testing with mobile showcase and will test it in our own application and production the next days.